# How to generate DataGrid.Columns from dymamic Xaml and add to an existing WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a [WPF Data Grid](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) that currently have columns generated at run-time. The columns are generated by a third-party  components and all I get is a string containing partial Xaml code that is basically like "<DataGrid.Columns> ..... </DataGrid.Columns>"

My question is, how do I compile it at run-time and add to existing DataGrid?
I have heard of XamlReader, I am not sure if it will allow me to do that ? I have searched the internet and found mostly Full Xaml compilation, not partial.

Thanks

Comment: From what I know `XamlReader` does render string to actual code. Never used tho. You may have something [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/08/dynamically-generating-controls-in-wpf-and-silverlight)

Comment: When you generate your grid it always have the same properties or it can change? For example: Sometimes you get ID,Name,Address, and sometimes ID,Name...

Comment: @Vinicius It can change.

Comment: I thought about creating a static grid with all rows you need and them populate based on what you get from your third party component.
You could give a collection of the same time as DataContext to your grid, bind property to columns and change the datacontext at run-time, giving a collection generated from what you`ve got? Did you get it ?

Comment: Instead of changing your Grid layout you would generate items from your xaml or maybe xml (XmlReader) and them populate the grid only.